# Moving files with the same name but different extension

Tags: batch-file

I'm using the ERP Bext, Bext generate .txt and .top files which is requiered. 
The goal of the Script is to move the files which have the same name, but different extension in the archive folder

Here is my Script :

```html
@echo off
title Script-Tri-Bext
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
cd "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex"
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\archive" mkdir archive
::alt va contenir les .top et les .txt non trié 
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\alt" mkdir alt
echo "Configuration : OK"
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
:: Tri des fichiers par paire
for %%i in ("C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex*.top") do (
    if exist "%%.txt" (
        echo "Successfully"
        move /y "%%~i" "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\archive"
        move /y "%%~.top" "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\archive"
    )
)

ping localhost -n 2 > nul
:: 
pause
```

Thanks :)

Comment: The `if exist "%%.txt" (` is msiing the for variable `i` and the `~` modifiers `%%~dpni.txt` if there are no other extensions than .txt/.top use one `move /y "%%~dpni.*" "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\archive"`

Comment: Thanks, man I was able to make it working properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
@echo off
title Script-Tri-Bext
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
cd "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex"
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\archive" mkdir archive
::alt va contenir les .top et les .txt non trié 
::IF NOT EXIST "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\alt" mkdir alt


@echo off &setlocal
for %%i in ("C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\srvbext\*.txt") do (
    if exist "%%~dpni.top" (
        echo "copie en cours"
        move /y "%%~i" "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\archive"
        echo "copie 1 fichier"
        move /y "%%~dpni.top" "C:\Users\ngallouj\Desktop\bex\archive"
    )
)

echo "Copie des fichiers : OK"
ping localhost -n 2 > nul
:: 
pause
```

Here is the fix